# cannot read property of when trying to send data from React to Express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mailgun

I'm trying to send some data from a React form to my Express back end. To do this I'm using `fetch` where I'm trying to send some variable data from react. I'm console logging the data before running the fetch to see if it is there, console log can see the data. 
My error states

```
[0] (node:2966) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
```

So it seems like my Express back end can't see the variable data.

How I'm sending  the data from react

```
handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Submit was pressed!");
    if (this.state.email === "") {
    }
    const { name } = this.state;
    const query = this.state.query;
    const subject = "kontakt fra nettside";
    const message = { name, query };
    console.log(message.name, message.text, "data is");
    fetch(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/email", variabler
      {
        method: "POST",
        cache: "no-cache",
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
          content_type: "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(message, subject)
      }
    ); //.then(response => response.json());
  };
```

My file for retrieving the data from the front end in Express

```
 const emailConfig = require("./emailConfig")();
    const mailgun = require("mailgun-js")(emailConfig);
    exports.sendEmail = (recipient, message, attachment) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const data = {
          from: "Test <test@test.no>", // Real email removed from this post
          to: recipient,
          subject: message.subject,
          text: message.query,
          inline: attachment,
          html: message.html
        };

        mailgun.messages().send(data, error => {
          if (error) {
            return reject(error);
          }
          return resolve();
        });
      });
```

and sendMail.js

```
const express = require("express");
const sendMail = express.Router();
const emailUtil = require("./emailUtil");
const { sendEmail } = emailUtil;
sendMail.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  // const { recipient, message } = req.body;
  console.log("Request mottatt");
  const recipient = "test@test.no";
  const message = req.body.message;
  try {
    await sendEmail(recipient, message);
    res.json({ message: "Your query has been sent" });
    console.log("Message has been sent");
    await next();
  } catch (e) {
    await next(e);
    console.log("nah", e);
  }
});
module.exports = sendMail;
```

I can't figure out where the error is, any ideas? :)

Comment: Where do you call `sendEmail`?

Comment: from my server.js file 
https://dpaste.de/dKkY
If I hardcode message data I can send mails by calling the URL via postman (using POST)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, shouldn't you have `req` / `res` on the controller to handle what's coming in?

Comment: I'm doing this in a different file, calling sendMail
https://dpaste.de/Kmvx

Comment: Ah this is what I was looking for :) Do you have body parser set up?

Comment: I did not! I've added one to my server.js 

`app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
); `
The problem still persists though

Comment: I also added `app.use(bodyParser.json());` to my server.js

Comment: Can you post your updated code?

Comment: https://dpaste.de/iWQu <- Server.js
https://dpaste.de/n3zU <- emailUtil.js
https://dpaste.de/fNVd <- sendMail.js 
I can update my post code later, or now if you'd prefer that

Comment: Hmm, that seems fine. I think the issue is your `JSON.stringify()`. Try: `JSON.stringify({ message })`.

Comment: forgot to add full front end code for the component
https://dpaste.de/zPjf

Comment: I tried passing only `body: JSON.stringify({ message })` and ` body: JSON.stringify({ message, subject })` in my front end code now, but the problem still persists

Comment: I don't see why that would be. Did you reload the server? I'll check back in a few hours if it's not resolved yet.

Comment: Yes, I've even rebooted my computer.